# rewrite setting in other jar - typesafe config

Tags: scala, configuration, playframework, typesafe-stack

In my classpath, there is a jar `a.jar` with `reference.conf` **file** in it. In the application, I read a config, let's say `config.myConfig1` with value `true`. I have another project in the classpath `b.jar` with `application.conf` **file** in it. I want to rewrite the original `config.myConfig1` with `false`.

I just placed the `application.conf` in the jar with the hope that it will get rewritten but it didn't happen. The value defined in `reference.conf` appeared in the application. What do I need to do in order to make it happen?

FYI, I read the config with `play`:

```
class MyPlugin(app: Application) extends Plugin with Logging {
  app.configuration.getStringList("config.myConfig1")

  // ...
```

Comment: Not sure that this will help, but typesafe allows you to specify exact  config file with `-Dconfig.file=application.conf` jvm parameter

Comment: @om-nom-nom well, I want it to merge, there is some config in `reference.conf`, that I don't want to override

Comment: You're talking about overriding *some* of the values from `reference.conf` with newly defined ones in your `config.myConfig1`, right? I'm not able to 100% verify that it will be merged with reference one, but it looks like it would. You could try and verify it by yourself, using `-Dconfig.trace=loads` with parameter given above.

Comment: @om-nom-nom well `config.myConfig1` is not file, but a value in the file, I edited the question, anyway I can still follow your advice and see what it does

Answer (score 0):

application.conf values should override reference.conf values; my guess is that there's just some small typo or equivalent keeping this from working.